# Export GRASS raster as GeoTIFF : nodata values exported as -nan (what happens in R?)

Tags: raster, grass-gis, r, geotiff-tiff, missing-data

I am using the package raster to work with GeoTIFF raster files which I exported from GRASS using r.out.gdal. GRASS assigned the value -nan to some raster files (type FLOAT32) for missing values. Other files had 65535 or 255 assigned to missing values.

In R, I reassign these values to missing like this:

`raster[raster==255] <- NA`

The problem is that I do not know what to do with multiple rasters that had the `-nan` assigned to missing values. For what I see when I examine the structure of these rasters (which I have as part of a list), the -nan are stored as NaN.I tried doing:

`rasterlist[["element_i"]][rasterlist[["element_i"]] == NaN] <- NA`

but I do not see any difference, for example when I do:

`getValues(rasterlist[["element_i"]], row=1000)`

The output is something like:

`8100 NaN 8101 NaN NaN 8102 8104 8106`

so the NaN are not transformed into NA.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

A NaN is different than NA. The NaN often results from a divide by zero error whereas NA is the R value for no data. These values behave in specific ways and it would be good for you to read some R background material to understand the behavior. Two useful operators to be aware of are: is.na() and is.nan().

```
y=c(0,1,2,3,4,NA)
x=c(0,1,2,3,4,NA)
(d=x/y)

is.na(d)
is.nan(d)

d[is.nan(d)] <- NA 
d

( d = c(NaN, 1:10, NA) )
d[d <= 5 | is.nan(d)] <- NA
d
```

Please keep in mind that the way you are vectorizing the problem is causing the entire raster to be read into memory. To keep the problem memory safe pass a function, setting NA's and replacing NaN's, to calc.

Comment: I was going to pass a function but I have the following problem. My raster for elevation may have the value 255. When I write a function like:                                                             raster_na <- function(rast) {
   for (i in 1:length(raster.list){
    rast[[vars]][rast[[vars]]== c(255,65535)] <- NA
  }
  return(rast)
}     I may convert an elevation value into NA, right?

Comment: Your function cannot be passed to calc. You need something that is vectorized like the example that I provided. Take a look at the help for calc.

Comment: So if I just say, for example `raster[raster == 65535] <- NA` that would work?

Comment: I think I got it. fun_na = function(raster){raster[raster==255] <- NA}

Comment: and then  new_values = calc(old_raster, func_na)

Comment: But actually this read it into memory as well

Comment: Almost. Something like this will set 255, 65535 and NaN values to NA: calc(r, function(x) {x[x == 255 | x == 65535 | is.nan(x)] <- NA; return(x) })  If you read the help for calc you will see that, using the filename argument, you can specify a raster that is read to disk. If the raster is large and you define an output raster, the function will automatically read the data in blocks to keep it memory safe.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this one. I don't know why, but using the function only with one raster did read the data and load it in memory :(

Answer (score 0):

A pesky feature of rasters is the multitude of "no data" possibilities, and how software doesn't consistently deal with it. What I expect that GRASS is doing is assigning minus infinity to the missing values.

While not the best of options, you could try to go about it the other way around, eg. identify all acceptable values and then assign NA to the ones not accepted.
In R I'd do it like this:

```
raster[!(raster<255 & raster>=0)] <- NA
```