# Removing NaN from raster using ArcGIS Pro 2.0.1?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro

I have an image (RGB) with a lot of NaN pixels (black) and I want them to have no color for visualization on a map.

My raster is derived surface reflectance values from Sentinel 2. After atmospheric correction I stacked the blue, green and red band in R and exported the rasterStack (.tif) to ArcGIS Pro for making a map of the RGB raster on a basemap.

I have added a basemap that cannot be seen due to the black color and when I click the pixels I also see that they have No Data (nan)

But I cant seem to get rid of the black color. When I look in Symbology, background and NoData already is set to No Color. When I try to change the color of No Data, it has no effect.

How can I make my black NaN pixels no color/transparent using ArcGIS Pro?

Edit: I have added a picture showing the edge of my raster against the basemap, and the information I get when I click a black pixel.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably they have no color but your background looks black. Check by placing a big colored polygon underneath.

Comment: actually I have a basemap as background, I see it around my raster when I zoom out, so it should be possible to see

Comment: What makes you think that black color is No Data?

Comment: What  are the precise steps that you have tried in ArcGIS Pro?  What version of ArcGIS Pro are you using?

Comment: I have the latest version, 2.0.1. When I click the pixel to get value information I see that it is nan. I have tried to change the NoData color and background color in Symbology, it has no effect.

Comment: Probably your system does not know yet that NaN means NoData and therefore setting NoData color in symbology does not have an effect.

Comment: I have the same problem in QGIS, however in R it is displayed properly (no color). Is it something I can fix somehow?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: In all the years I've been using raster datasets I have never seen ArcMap or  the new Pro return the value "nan" for a NoData cell. Edit your question and describe your raster format. Where did it come from, what processing had you done to it? Making NoData cells transparent should be a trivial task.

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope it is more clear. I agree, I have experience with ArcGIS as well. To make an RGB composite (of surface reflectance over water) I stacked the red, green and blue band in R and exported as a tif. When I open in ArcGIS i get this result, even though it was correctly displayed in R (no color around the water body).

Comment: So the source of the dataset you are attempting to display in Pro is this stacking process in R? I've never used R but that is where I would start looking, see if there is a parameter setting to define your NoData value.

Comment: Suggest you read this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135818/export-grass-raster-as-geotiff-nodata-values-exported-as-nan-what-happens-in/135836#135836).

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is from a few years back but incase anyone else has this issue ( I just did)  you can get rid of the odd "nan" value by using the ArcGIS Pro raster calculator and multiplying the raster by 1. This turns the "nan" into NoData which is easy to get rid of.